# What is the difference between declare and typeset?

Tags: bash, typeset

Can anyone explain the difference between `declare` and `typeset` with real-life examples?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In `bash`, `typeset` and `declare` are exactly the same. The only difference is that `typeset` is considered obsolete.

```
typeset: typeset [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] name[=value] ...
    Set variable values and attributes.

    Obsolete.  See `help declare'.
```

The man page even lists them in the same breath:

```
declare [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
typeset [-aAfFgilrtux] [-p] [name[=value] ...]
    Declare variables and/or give them attributes.
```

`typeset` is portable to some other shells, for example, `ksh93`. If you are aiming for cross-shell portability, use `typeset` (and make sure that the way you are calling it is portable). If you don't care about such portability, use `declare`.

Comment: can you please provide some example of where and why this use in bash script

Comment: ...like I said, they are exactly the same. I don't understand how I can differentiate them if they are so.

Comment: Good one. Note that "obsolete" just appears in `help typeset`, not in `man typeset`.

Comment: @ChrisDown, you wouldn't happen to know why, exactly, `typeset` is considered obsolete?

Comment: In bash 4.4 and later, it is changed to **synonym** instead of obsolete.
`help typeset` => `A synonym for \`declare'.  See \`help declare'.`

Answer (score 6):

I know a case where `declare` is useful to avoid the evil `eval` : *variable indirection* :

```
$ var=foo
$ x=var
$ declare "$x=another_value"
$ echo $var
another_value
```

Comment: This is a nice comment but how does that answer the question which is about `typeset` and `declare`?

Comment: This is already well answered by Chris Down, my response is just a case where it's usefull

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  Comments should be comments, and answers should be answers.  This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: My snippet wouldn't clear in a comment

Comment: but you still can assign variables with typeset... just replace declare with typeset and you still get the same result.